# Sequelize mixes camel case and snake case keys in result object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Am trying to get the resulting plain object from Sequelize create (or any Sequelize query) to be snake case keys throughout. The result objects are mixed however. Here's an example query:

```
const object = await models.Account.create({
  userId,
  name,
  accountNumber
})

console.log(object.get({ plain: true }))
```

The result object is mixed keys of camel case and snake case:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "baller",
    "accountNumber": "1234-123-1234",
    "updated_at": "2019-01-07T02:23:41.305Z",
    "created_at": "2019-01-07T02:23:41.305Z",
    "balance": "0.00",
    "deleted_at": null
}
```

Any idea how to get the result plain object or nested objects to be completely snake case keys only? Upgrade sequelize from ^4.42.0 to ^5.0.0-beta in package.json and happens for both. Not sure what else to try?

Accounts table is all snake case column names:

```
return queryInterface.createTable('accounts', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  user_id: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: 'users',
      key: 'id'
    }
  },
  name: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
  },
  account_number: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
  },
```

Account model has has option underscored: true and camelCase attrs with field in snake case

```
const Account = sequelize.define('Account', {
  userId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field: 'user_id',
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notNull(value) {
        if (value == null) {
          throw new Error('Missing user id')
        }
      }
    }
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    field: 'name',
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    }
  },
  accountNumber: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    field: 'account_number',
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    }
  },
}, {
  tableName: 'accounts',
  paranoid: true,
  underscored: true
})
```

Comment: It looks like this is implemented in sequelize.js v5 https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#model

Comment: Upgraded from ^4.42.0 to ^5.0.0-beta but mixing is still happening. Anything else to try?

Comment: Did you apply the `underscored` attribute?

Comment: Yes underscored:true is in the Model definition above. Should it be elsewhere?

Comment: it looks like [the change](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/9304) was put into 5.0.0-beta.3. Make sure you have at least that version.

Comment: Tried but issue still there

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm resolving it with:

```
import snakeCaseKeys from 'snakecase-keys'

let jsonObject = object.get({ plain: true })
jsonObject = snakeCaseKeys(jsonObject)
```